# Equalizing boxes with same space vertically but different Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to equalizing the top of my list items with variable height.
I also want every box to have the same space with each other as shown in the picture below:

[image: desired output]

Following is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="content">
        <li class="item">1 test test test test test test</li>
        <li class="item">2 test test test test test test test test test</li>
        <li class="item">3 test test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
        <li class="item">4 test test test test test test</li>
        <li class="item">5 test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 0px
}
.content {
    width:100%;
}
.item {
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:30px;
    width:100px;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    top:0;
}
```

and here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdp1708/d7tkV/3/) need your help to solve it.

Comment: Please include your code within the question. If jsfiddle goes down, this would have been unanswerable. Also, it sounds like you want to try the Masonry plugin.

Comment: thanks a lot. i'm beginner using stackoverflow. thanks for your advice. next time i'll do :)

Comment: right now it is equal size only.

Comment: yes of course vanio178

Comment: actually i want my boxes looks like this, Suresh 
https://d8e7ec01-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/vanyfiles/looks%20like%20this.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7co9tKXkFtsohysfYpFUzthUqmNTu3C3ckkAmBqzTcQnvoxFGWRCkRFEEDxFy8USFh7rMVAuexF8allM9fUTn6KLRY8jLNaHkgZPeGbfCO77xpbXzRoIWPZLbi13A2zzQ9NaXp4sijL80xWtwmlGZxqtqa29zmlhrH4aDR8l3QWiFTTQgSofKjyDCXRf5d5ACVe-OnforWqHElTTIly98C5quOr7Mw%3D%3D&attredirects=1

Comment: yeahh thanks a lot. thanks for everyone who suggest me using Masonry plugin. i'm already using it now. Nice! :D u make my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, apply

```
vertical-align:top;
```

For the  `.item`'s.

(*`top` has no effect on statically positioned elements*)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7tkV/6/)

**Update**:

If you want the vertical space between the boxes to be equal, you can make use of [css3 flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) as follows (*The order of boxes will be different though*):

```
.content {
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d7tkV/8/)

If you want to keep the order exactly as shown in the pic, then you'll probably need to rely on plugins like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)

Answer (score 0):

U want to make this? http://jsfiddle.net/BuaC3/

```
.wrapper{padding:0}
.content{width:100%;}
.item{background:blue; margin:0 5px 5px;float:right; color:white; padding:30px; width:100px; list-style:none; display:inline-block;top:0; }
```

Comment: once again pls. but the boxes in 2nd row should be sticked on the boxes in 1st row and  has the same space vertically :) looks like my blog

Comment: sorry for my bad english. mmmm i'm updated my question . there's an image to explain what i want 
https://d8e7ec01-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/vanyfiles/looks%20like%20this.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7co9tKXkFtsohysfYpFUzthUqmNTu3C3ckkAmBqzTcQnvoxFGWRCkRFEEDxFy8USFh7rMVAuexF8allM9fUTn6KLRY8jLNaHkgZPeGbfCO77xpbXzRoIWPZLbi13A2zzQ9NaXp4sijL80xWtwmlGZxqtqa29zmlhrH4aDR8l3QWiFTTQgSofKjyDCXRf5d5ACVe-OnforWqHElTTIly98C5quOr7Mw%3D%3D&attredirects=1

Comment: thanks for helping :) but i can't use 3 columns like that, bcause i'll make looping for that box which is it used for item postings in my website

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/d7tkV/7/)

Added the following rules to the `.item` class.

```
.item{
    vertical-align: top; /* alignment */
    margin-top: 10px /* breathing space */
}
```